# Maximum execution time exceeded on json_decode

Tags: php

When I upgraded my php from 5.5 to 5.6, it started throwing maximum execution time on json_decode.

1. `return = json_decode($row[0], true);` in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/RecentTable.class.php`
2. `if( json_decode( $result ) ) return json_decode( $result );` in `/var/sites/test.example.com/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth2Client.php`
3. Something as simple as : `$json ='{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';var_dump(json_decode($json));exit;` is causing execution time out.

Everything was working fine in php 5.5.Can anyone please explain the reason?

Comment: try this ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

Comment: @AnkurTiwari This is some issue with json_decode.Increasing the execution time is not the solution.

Comment: @johndoe are all the conditions same ? as in the json data that you are trying to decode ?

Comment: @georoot One json_decode is in phpmyadmin file while other is in auth plugin.

Comment: @johndoe as you can compare the json decoder files in [5.5](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/php-src/PHP-5.5/ext/json/JSON_parser.c) and [5.6](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/php-src/PHP-5.6/ext/json/JSON_parser.c) there is no change in them. I am guessing it is something to do with your configuration,which might have changed during upgrade

Comment: here is also a diff just to prove the case [diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/azpebqgs) , i would suggest that you edit the question and add configuration that you were using and that of the latest one